# WordPress PHP Warning: parse_url(://:80/blog/xmlrpc.php)

Tags: php, wordpress

I checked my Apache's error log on my WordPress site, and every time I update a post (select post and click 'update') I get this error:

> [Wed Apr 06 11:35:21 2011] [error]
>   [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning: 
>   parse_url(://:80/blog/xmlrpc.php):
>   Unable to parse URL in
>   /home/webuser/public_html/domain.com/public/wp-includes/class-http.php
>   on line 241

It looks like it's not getting a valid URL passed to the parse_url function.  Anyone know where I should look to fix this?

The site seems to load and update fine, but this error has me concerned.  Thanks for any assistance!

Edit 1: I checked line 241 on /wp-includes/class-http.php and here's the code:

```
 236                 // Allow plugins to short-circuit the request
 237                 $pre = apply_filters( 'pre_http_request', false, $r, $url );
 238                 if ( false !== $pre )
 239                         return $pre;
 240
 241                 $arrURL = parse_url( $url );
```

Comment: ehm ... look at `/home/webuser/public_html/domain.com/public/wp-includes/class-http.php on line 241`?

Comment: Look up the same timestamp in the access log (within a second or two) to find the url of the request that caused the error. should give you an idea of where to look.

Comment: @King: that's where the error is logged, but the it's just a handler function, and the bad url was generated elsewhere.

Comment: @Marc: I didnt looked at the source. I just assumed, that there is something like `parse_url($url)`, from where @coasthird can trace up to find, where `$url` is constructed.

Comment: @KingCrunch - line 241 = $arrURL = parse_url( $url); I've updated my original post to include this line and the preceding code.

Comment: @Marc B - I've tested it, and it happens when I click an existing post, and select 'Update'.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Wordpress is trying to reach out to someone's XMLRPC endpoint, but the URL is malformed.  The fact that the path is `/blog/xmlrpc.php` while your WP install doesn't seem to live in `/blog` suggests it's *not* your XMLRPC endpoint that's being looked for.

Check your settings, you might have it configured to perform an XMLRPC request somewhere whenever you create or update a post.  A plugin may also cause this.